# Объект игнорирует коллайдеры, что делать?

Tags: unity3d

На объекте висят `SpriteRenderer`, `BoxCollider` и `RigidBody`. На сцене есть неподвижные объекты с `BoxCollider`, и мой объект не может пройти сквозь них - в общем, ведет себя как любой порядочный объект, который встречается с неподвижным `BoxCollider` С помощью скрипта я двигаю объект по сцене (по осям X и Y; Z остается без изменений):

```
private Vector3 screenPoint;

private Vector3 offset; 

void OnMouseDown() {
    offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
}
void OnMouseDrag() 
{ 
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
    if (canMoveWithDrag)
    transform.position = curPosition;
}
```

Но теперь он начинает проходить сквозь другие `BoxCollider` как будто их нет. Стоит мне только отпустить кнопку мыши, когда я держу объект, как он тут же вспоминает про существование других коллайдеров. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при drag-and-drop мой объект не игнорировал другие коллайдеры?
П.С тема выросла отсюда, там пытался найти решение. Может, есть варианты проще (в плане производительности)?
[Как повернуть точки на объекте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676166/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment987863_676166)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Comment: Да с физикой все в порядке, она не игнорирует коллайдеры, просто у тебя физика обрабатывается, но потом ты в MouseDrag новую позицию выставляешь, в итоге объект обратно ставится, и поэтому ничего не происходит. А как только убирает мышь, так сразу все нормально.

Comment: @KremSoda Так и не понятно, надо чтобы объект не выходил за пределы экрана? или чтобы не мог проходить через boxcollider'ы?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ и то, и то (на границах тоже стоят boxcollider). Щас пытаюсь AddForce правильный настроить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мда, оказывается, в бесплатной Standart Assets у Unity уже есть класс `DragRigidbody`, который делает то, что мне нужно